# Extracting the values from dictionary with tuple

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tuples, svm

I'm working on support vector machine where I extracted the best parameters for polynomial, linear and RBF using **gridsearchcv** . I wanted to separate C and degree values so that I can call the best parameters for my dataset for the fit function where I can compute the accuracy with the tuned parameters.

The dictionary with tuple is

({'C': 1, 'degree': 1}, {'C': 0.1, 'degree': 1}, {'C': 1, 'degree': 1})

I tried using

```
for i in c.items():
        value=i
    print(value)
```

But got error:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'

The progress of my code is:

```
 def svc_param_selection(self, X, y, nfolds):
    #We tune two hyperparameters C and d using svc_param_selection
    #the slack penalty hyperparameter
    Cs = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
    #degrees of polynomial kernel of svc
    degrees = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    #initialize the paremeter grid as dictionary
    param_grid = {'C': Cs, 'degree' : degrees}
    #initialize search for best parameters using input nfold cross validation
    search = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(kernel='poly'), param_grid, cv=nfolds)
    search1 = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(kernel='linear'), param_grid, cv=nfolds)
    search2 = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(kernel='rbf'), param_grid, cv=nfolds)
    #fit the search object to input training data
    search.fit(X, y)
    search1.fit(X, y)
    search2.fit(X, y)
    #return the best parameters
    search.best_params_
    search1.best_params_
    search2.best_params_
    print("[*] Searching for the best parameters for fitting the data.......")
    print("Parameters are :")
    #print(search.best_params_)
    #print(search1.best_params_)
    #print(search2.best_params_)
    return search.best_params_,search1.best_params_,search2.best_params_


def param_sel(self):
    X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test=self.norm()
    #self.svc_param_selection(X_train, y_train, 10)
    degree=np.array([])
    c= self.svc_param_selection(X_train, y_train, 10)
    print(c)
    for i in c.items():
        value=i
    print(value)


def fit(self):
    X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test=self.norm()
    final_svc_poly1 = svm.SVC(C=1, degree=1, kernel='poly')
    final_svc_poly2 = svm.SVC(C=1, degree=1, kernel='linear')
    final_svc_poly3 = svm.SVC(C=1, degree=1, kernel='rbf')

    final_svc_poly1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    final_svc_poly2.fit(X_train, y_train)
    final_svc_poly3.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("[*] Computing accuracy of test dataset")
    print("Accuracy with polynomial kernel",final_svc_poly1.score(X_test, y_test))
    print("Accuracy with linear kernel",final_svc_poly2.score(X_test, y_test))
    print("Accuracy with RBF kernel",final_svc_poly3.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Output:

```
[*] Searching for the best parameters for fitting the data.......
Parameters are :
({'C': 1, 'degree': 1}, {'C': 0.1, 'degree': 1}, {'C': 1, 'degree': 1})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-4be4dd58a851> in <module>
      1 if __name__=='__main__':
----> 2     main()

<ipython-input-105-7b466d716ef5> in main()
      7     #X_train,y_train=first.split_data()
      8     #print(X_train)
----> 9     param=second.param_sel()
     10     second.fit()

<ipython-input-104-57f0d958ed41> in param_sel(self)
     69         c= self.svc_param_selection(X_train, y_train, 10)
     70         print(c)
---> 71         for i in c.items():
     72             value=i
     73         print(value)
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value - `C=({'C': 1, 'degree': 1}, {'C': 0.1, 'degree': 1}, {'C': 1, 'degree': 1})` is a tuple of dictionaries, hence it has no attribute `items`.

You can iterate over the tuple with -

```
for item in C:
    print(item)
```

So, fixing according to the clarification -

```
c_values = []
degrees = []
for item in C:
    c_values.append(item['C'])
    degrees.append(item['degree'])
```

btw - in your loop you override value in each iteration any print it outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I progressed a little, but still I got like {C:1, degree:1} and next one by the iteration, I want to create an array where I can store all C values and another array to store degrees.

Comment: @DevanshMishra I edited my answer according to your comment

Comment: It still gives the error TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: When i changed in the loop,c_values.append(C['C']) by c_values.append(item['C']). It runs fine. Thanks :)